# generate nofollow links in RDiscount output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown, rdiscount

My rails app is using RDiscount to generate HTML from user-supplied markdown text, and I noticed that the anchor tags don't have rel="nofollow".  This is a big issue for me as my app is open to the public.  Is there a way to enable nofollow links, or are there better solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is possible only with [Kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html#reference-links), which is a ruby Markdown parser with extended syntax. You would do that then as shown in the link:

```
[link](test.html){:rel='nofollow'}
```

Comment: Actually the content will be supplied by the user, so I need a way to automatically add rel="nofollow" to every link as a measure to discourage SEO spam.  I think stackoverflow does it.

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time, I am using this hack, by re-parsing the RDiscount output and add a rel="nofollow" to each anchor:

```
def markdown(input)
  html = RDiscount.new(input).to_html
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
  doc.css("a").each do |link|
    link['rel'] = 'nofollow'
  end
  doc.to_html
end
```

Though I think this should really be handled by the markdown parser.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar, add `target="_new"` to all links. Solved it using [Kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/) and a custom `Kramdown::Converter::Html` class.

Define a `Kramdown::Converter::Html` subclass (kramdown/converter/my_html.rb in some autoload path)

```
class Kramdown::Converter::MyHtml < Kramdown::Converter::Html
  def convert_a(el, indent)
    el.attr['target'] = '_new'
    super
  end
end
```

I also have a view helper in app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def markdown(str)
  Kramdown::Converter::MyHtml.convert(Kramdown::Document.new(str).root)[0].html_safe
end
```

Ideally it should be possible to just use `Kramdown::Document.new(str).to_my_html.html_safe` but I can't get it to work in rails development mode as Kramdown uses `const_defined?` to see if a converter is available and that does not trigger the autoloader. Please comment if you know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount/issues/27) on RDiscount to support modifying links in this fashion.

It is scheduled for one of the upcoming RDiscount 2.1.5.x releases.